# outlook addon to automatically save email data

Tags: .net, outlook-addin

I am very new to .Net and facing issue. I am working on a outlook addon, Addon will do following things, automatically save email content to excel sheet, email content can be in different format but output will be in defined format. I have seen some solutions to save email and attachments. If it is simple email thn may be I can go for some VBA solution but email can have attachment as well.

please guide on this, how can I achieve this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Outlook object model is common for all kind of applications. It doesn't matter whether you develop an Outlook add-in or VBA macro. The same API is available for developers. See [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

The Outlook object model provides three main ways for working item bodies:

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx) -  a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item.
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx) - a string representing the HTML body of the specified item.
3. [Word editor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) - the Microsoft Word Document Object Model of the message being displayed. The WordEditor property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Document class from the Word object model which you can use to set up the message body.

You can read more about all these ways in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

The Attachment class from the Outlook object model provides the [SaveAsFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa210277%28v=office.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method which allows to save the attachment to the specified path.